# MySQL: Modifying a query based on EXPLAIN plan

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a long running query that I'd like to speed up. The result of the query is a new table.

The tables are all MYISAM and it is running on a large EC2 instance (m2.4xlarge, 64GB RAM).

System usage looks like this:

```
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                            
17438 mysql     20   0 32.7g 7.1g 7420 S    2 10.6   1:35.82 mysqld
```

Relevant portion of my cnf:

```
key_buffer      = 32768M
max_allowed_packet  = 96M
thread_stack    = 192K
thread_cache_size   = 8
sort_buffer_size    = 2M
read_buffer_size    = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M


table_cache             = 512
thread_concurrency      = 8
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 2048M
max_write_lock_count    = 1

# ~1/4 of memory of machine
max_heap_table_size = 16384M 
tmp_table_size      = 16384M

# ~1/4 of memory
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 17179869184
```

When I run this simple query, it takes much longer than I think it should and memory and CPU usage on the machine is low.

The query explain plan looks like this:

```
mysql> explain SELECT encounter_id
-> FROM encounters e, sampled_patients sp
-> WHERE e.patient_id = sp.patient_id;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+--------------------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref                | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+--------------------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sp    | index | patient_id    | patient_id | 4       | NULL               | 1537954 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | e     | ref   | patient_id    | patient_id | 5       | noah.sp.patient_id |       1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+--------------------+---------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

It has to look through ~1.5M rows, but it's indexed. How can I speed this up?

Comment: It's been running for 1.5 hours. I'd like to do more joins like this on much larger (10x) tables, so I'm curious how to optimize. The filters are already applied, the sampled_patients table is a subset of a much larger table. There is no further filtering to be applied.

Comment: @zimmeee: more joins != more complicated.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: hm, how did you know about 10Gb of data?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean more as in: increase the number of joins. I meant more as in: doing similar queries on other tables where the row count is much larger.

Comment: Note that the query completed after 2hr 36m